# Solutions to the PDE $u_t=i u_x$ st. $\int |u|^2 dx < \infty$ and $\frac{d}{dt} \int |u|^2 dx = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE $u_t=i u_x$ where $u(x,t):\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$ is assumed to be a $C^1$ function.

Are there any non trivial solutions for which $\int_\mathbb{R} |u(x,t)|^2 dx < \infty$ and $\frac{d}{dt} \int_\mathbb{R} |u(x,t)|^2 dx = 0$?

I know there are solutions of the form $u(x,t) = e^{k(t-ix)}$ for any complex $k$, however these solutions don't obey the integral conditions that I would like to hold.

Comment: @JJacquelin, thx for pointing that out, I just updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your solution is sufficiently smooth, we have
$$
(\partial_t+i\partial_x)\underbrace{(\partial_t-i\partial_x)u}_{=0}=(\partial_{tt}+\partial_{xx})u=\Delta u=0.
$$
Hence your solution is a harmonic function and has harmonic real and imaginary part. Your condition
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}Re(u)^2 dx \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|u|^2 dx<\infty
$$
ensures that the real part has also bounded $L^2$-norm. We can therefore use the mean value property to infer that
$$
|Re(u(x))| \leq \frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_{B_r(x)}|Re(u(y))|dy
$$
and further estimate with the help of Hölder inequality for $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$
$$
|Re(u(x))| \leq  ||Re(u)||_{L^2(B_r(x))}  ||\frac{1}{\pi r^2}||_{L^2(B_r(x))} \leq ||Re(u)||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \frac{1}{r\sqrt{\pi}}.
$$
Sending $r \to \infty$ yields the desired result that $Re(u(x))$ must be $0$. You can argue the same way for the imaginary part.

Comment: I believe you mean to integrate over $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^2$ for your second eqauation, otherwise your answer seems fine to me and seems to show that there are no such non trivial solutions. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I just noted I read your assumptions a bit wrong :/  
I think nevertheless you can do sth with your function being harmonic.

Comment: I just cleaned up my question a little, hopefully this makes things more clear. What do you mean by 'sth'?

Comment: I assumed your function would have finite $L^2$ norm over $\mathbb{R}^2$ for some reason. Maybe one can recover this condition nevertheless by using the second condition on the $L^2$-norm.

Comment: Nevertheless, I assume that you can find a contradiction using the fact that your function is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^2$, even if my proof turns out to be unsalvageable

Comment: Thanks again, I'll accept this answer as I think it gives me enough of a pointer in the right direction to get a proof.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry again for the confusion. Feel free to unaccept mine if you/someone else posts a complete answer.